# Clipping one column in a variable-width HTML table

Tags: html, css

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KDfTN/

I have a table for which one column will *sometimes* contain extra-long content. Normally I want the table to stay at its natural width (i.e. not filling its container). However, if the natural width would be larger than the container, I want to cut off the extra-long content with an ellipsis. As shown in the link, I've tried what I think is the correct way of doing this, but it doesn't work: The table just keeps growing past the width of its container. Any ideas or suggestions?

**Edit:** The width of the table's container is not fixed, just as it is in the JSFiddle interface.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Set `max-width:300px;` on `td.long` (or whatever width you want)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the width of the table's container is not fixed, so I can't apply absolute dimensions to any part of the table. I've amended the original question.

Comment: Well, you need some sort of size constraint in order for the ellipsis to be triggered. You may want to try putting some percentages on the table columns.

Comment: I don't want to apply sizing to the columns, because I want them to be only as wide as they need to be to fit the content (all columns have variable-width content). When the "as wide as it needs to be" rule results in the table being wider than its container, I want to clip the text in the "long" column. In other words, I want the same behavior seen in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/EBQkk/1/, except I want the long column to clip, instead of running onto multiple lines.